# How can I connect a Linux box to an Azure AD-Authenticated VPN?

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, azure, azure-activedirectory

I've been tearing my hair out over this - a client is using an Azure VPN setup that seems to only play nicely specifically with the Azure VPN Client app. It works perfectly on that software, but I need to use Linux to do the work. Is there any to connect to this on Linux?

I've tried various Strongswan/IKE, OpenVPN, and PPTP/SSTP configurations and solutions. Unfortunately it's hard to know whether I've been one slight configuration away from success or totally off-point. Hopefully I'm being silly and it's not Microsoft being a unhelpful PITA.

In addition to a VpnServerRoot.cer file, I've been given the VpnSettings folder from Azure, in this format (details obscured):

```
<VpnProfile>
  <VpnServer>azuregateway-aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa.vpn.azure.com</VpnServer>
  <VpnType>OpenVPN</VpnType>
  <CaCert>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaetc=</CaCert>
  <Routes>10.0.1.0/24,10.0.2.0/24</Routes>
  <Auth>EAPTLS</Auth>
  <VnetName>foobar</VnetName>
  <VnetId>aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa</VnetId>
  <ServerCertRootCn>Foo Root CA</ServerCertRootCn>
  <ServerCertIssuerCn>Foo Root CA</ServerCertIssuerCn>
  <VpnClientAddressPool>10.0.1.0/24</VpnClientAddressPool>
  <AadIssuer>https://sts.windows.net/aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa/</AadIssuer>
  <AadTenant>https://login.microsoftonline.com/aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa</AadTenant>
  <AadAudience>aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa</AadAudience>
  <CustomDnsServers>10.0.1.1</CustomDnsServers>
</VpnProfile>
```

How do I manipulate this information to connect my Linux box to the AAD-authed VPN?

I'm currently using Fedora 34, but I'm willing to take a convoluted workaround or even change distro if I have to.

Comment: OpenVPN with EAP-TLS? Now that's an unusual combination.